# how to see annotation for changed lines in Intellij IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

[Annotate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-annotations.html#d1020052e271) menu in Intellij shows last author of unchaned lines. 
Is there an option to show annotation for modified lines (for changed lines that have not been submitted yet)? Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: It *does* show last updated person's name against modified lines. Can you clarify?

Comment: attached a screenshot. thanks

Comment: I see what you mean. But I think it makes logical sense to not annotate any lines that you are still editing. We know for sure that is _you_ .

Comment: I would like to see who was the previous author of the line, and I cant do that unless I undo my changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you won't see annotations for the lines with local and uncommitted modifications. You are the author of these changes and it would be confusing to put info about previous versions of these lines. However, I guess that you could open a new window with the file that you work with and run [**Annotate Revision** command](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-annotations.html#d1331490e208) specifying HEAD revision in the repository. This will help you view blame info without your local modifications.

Comment: genius, I didn't think about it